# NodeJS Module exports / prototype - has no method

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got a module that looks like this:

```
var MyModule = module.exports = function MyModule(opts) {

    opts = (opts === Object(opts)) ? opts : {};

    if (!(this instanceof MyModule)) {
        return new MyModule(opts);
    }

    for (var key in opts) if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(opts, key)) {
        this.config[key] == opts[key];
    }
};

MyModule.prototype.config = {
    something:'value'
}

MyModule.prototype.put = function put(info, cb) {
   //do stuff

};
```

However, when I use it like this:

```
var myModule = require('myModule.js');

myModule.put({test}, function(){
    //some callback stuff
});
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: Object function MyModule(opts) {
>
> ```
> opts = (opts === Object(opts)) ? opts : {};
>
> if (!(this instanceof MyModule)) {
>     return new MyModule(opts);
> }
>
> for (var key in opts) if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(opts, key)) {
>     this.config[key] == opts[key];
> } } has no method 'put'
> ```

It appears I have something wrong with my `MyModule.prototype.put` ?

Comment: I'm not sure why someone would downvote this question without good reason. Understanding the CommonJS modules system is a pretty important part to writing node.js code. Even if you understand the concept, but accidentally overlooked it... it's still a valid question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You wrote :

```
var myModule = require('myModule.js');

myModule.put({}, function(){
  //some callback stuff
});
```

Here `myModule` is in fact `MyModule`, a constructor function. So what you are doing is `MyModule.put()`, a call to a "static" method of `MyModule`. `MyModule.prototype.put` defines an "instance" method so you have to instanciate first :

```
var MyModule = require('./myModule.js');

var myModule = new MyModule();
// or as you used `if (!(this instanceof MyModule)) { … }`
var myModule = MyModule();

myModule.put({}, function () {});
```

So basically your code needs just a pair of `()` to work :

```
MyModule().put({}, function () {});
// same as
(new MyModule).put({}, function () {});
```

Récap :

```
var MyModule = function () {
  // Construct object
};

MyModule.staticMethod = function () {
  this; // is bound to `MyModule` function object
};

MyModule.prototype.instanceMethod = function () {
  this; // is bound to the `MyModule` instance object it’s called from
};

// Usage

MyModule.staticMethod();

var instance = new MyModule();
instance.instanceMethod();
```

Comment: but I had instance with "new" ,still can not get prototype functions after I module.exports  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996343/miss-prototype-functions-when-new-a-instance?noredirect=1#comment55752964_33996343

Answer (score 4):

With this code `var myModule = require('myModule.js');` your `myModule` variable looks like a constructor function, not an instance of myModule.

Try instantiating your module first:

```
var MyModule = require('myModule.js');    
var myModule = new MyModule(); // Create an instance of your module.

// Now use it.
myModule.put(/*... your code here ...*/);
```