# miss prototype functions when "new" a instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, commonjs

I write a module in nodejs ,which Test.js ,code blow

```
function Test() {
    this.key = 'value';
}
Test.prototype.foo = function () { return 'foo'; }
module.exports = Test;
```

and then, in B.js

```
var Test = require('./services/Test');
var test = new Test();
console.log(test.foo());
```

unfortunetly, I got "undefined method foo",
anyone who can Tell me what happended? thanks so much

[image: I create a Express sample project, and you can see the code ,still can not get the 'prototype']

Comment: in B.JS
var test = require('./services/Test');
console.log(test.foo());

Comment: Maybe your JS files are not in the right locations. when I copied your code it works. You can try it in a clean NodeJS app, and it will work. Also try to debug it. And let the IDE to auto-complete your Test file path.

Comment: I think the path is right, It can right "require",but wrong with "new"

Comment: What do `console.log(Test, test, test.key)` log?

Answer (score 0):

Check your file location it should be in services directory.

Comment: what I required is a Function, this step is ok, but ,when I "new ",prototype method is missing

Answer (score 0):

```
function Test() {
    this.key = 'value';
}
Test.prototype.foo = function () { return 'foo'; }
module.exports = new Test();//Test;


var test = require('./services/Test');
console.log(test.foo());
```

You can export the new object of Test class. try this.
Or you can use ES6 JavaScript that great.

Answer (score -2):

In **Test.js** try moving the module.exports to before you define the prototype functions.

As below:

```
function Test() {
    this.key = 'value';
}
module.exports = Test;
Test.prototype.foo = function () { return 'foo'; }
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing to the community.  However, before you answer you should check that it is in fact correct or have a strong suspicion that you are correct.  It feels as though this answer is a guess, and in fact when I try it I do not get the same behavior as the OP says.

Comment: I only posted this because I was looking for the solution my self. So I decided to see what modules I had included did, and found that they had put this before defining the functions via prototype. After I made this change, it worked for me.